# subset data using apply with a list of variables

Tags: r

This thread is continuation of my previous thread on combining `apply` function with multiconditional `subet`. I need to subset data based on time horizon (in years). I have multiple data frames each contains data from different year. I need to set time horizon and subset data based on it. I think it can be best explained using example:

```
set.seed(200)

#example data frames    
     df_2014=data.frame(colour=(c(rep("RED",10),rep("BLUE",10),rep("GREEN",10)))
               ,shade=c(rep(c(rep("LIGHT",5),rep("DARK",5)),3))
               ,year=c(rep(2011:2015,6))
               ,value=runif(30,min=0,max=1))

     df_2013=data.frame(colour=(c(rep("RED",10),rep("BLUE",10),rep("GREEN",10)))
               ,shade=c(rep(c(rep("LIGHT",5),rep("DARK",5)),3))
               ,year=c(rep(2011:2015,6))
               ,value=runif(30,min=0,max=1))

#time horizon, it can be +1,-2, any value. Its always constant
 horizon=+1

#subset functions for each df
    subset(df_2014, df_2014$colour %in% "BLUE" & df_2014$shade %in% "DARK" & df_2014$year %in% c(2014+horizon))
    subset(df_2013, df_2013$colour %in% "BLUE" & df_2013$shade %in% "DARK" & df_2013$year %in% c(2013+horizon))
```

The output is:

```
   colour shade year     value
20   BLUE  DARK 2015 0.6463296

   colour shade year     value
19   BLUE  DARK 2014 0.6532767
```

Thanks to kindness of user Rui Barradas i have two versions of `apply` function:

```
lapply(list.dfs, function(x) customSubset(x, "BLUE", "DARK"))
lapply(list.dfs, customSubset, "BLUE", "DARK")
```

Where `customSubset` is:

```
customSubset <- function(DF, COL, SHADE){
    subset(DF, colour %in% COL & shade %in% SHADE)
}
```

I need to add 3rd argument that will be possibly list of years (this is my "list of variables" like in thread title) referring to each df (as in example i have df that comes from many years like this: `list.dfs=list(df_2014,df_2013,df_2012,df_2011)`) and then store presented output as one data frame.

My first attempt was to create list of years `list.years=c(2014,2013,2012,2011)`, and I tried something like this:

```
#here i add new variable to customSubset:
customSubsetYEAR <- function(DF, COL, SHADE,year){
    subset(DF, colour %in% COL & shade %in% SHADE %in% year)
}

#horizon as in example
horizon=+1
```

`#here is adjusted(incorrectly) lapply function:
lapply(list.dfs, function(x) customSubset(x, "BLUE", "DARK",year.list[x]+horizon))`

Which is not working. If something is unclear please let me know. Any workaround is fine, except one with `for loop` which I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
list.dfs=list(df_2014,df_2013,df_2012,df_2011)

names(list.dfs)<-c(2014,2013,2012,2011) #or put some grep pattern to automate it
```

Function definition

```
customSubset <- function(DF, COL, SHADE , YEAR){
 subset(DF, colour %in% COL & shade %in% SHADE & year %in% YEAR) 
}
```

code

```
lapply(names(list.dfs), function(x) customSubset(list.dfs[[x]], "BLUE", "DARK",as.numeric(x)+horizon))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I applied your solution to my real data and it worked properly. I have one question about the output - when i write it down in xlsx or csv columns are placed next to each other. For more clear presentation of what I have in mind do this: `x=lapply(names(list.dfs), function(x) customSubset(list.dfs[[x]], "BLUE", "DARK",as.numeric(x)+horizon))` and the `write.csv(x, path="")`. Is there any simple way to store them as rows in data frame?

Comment: I did not get your question clearly. Do you want to write csv also along with each lapply? If yes , change the function definition as t1<-subset(.....) and then write.csv(t1) followed by return(t1)

Comment: No, I want to store output in one joint data frame. Csv was only an example of how I do NOT want my data stored. Or possibly create empty data frame and then put `lapply` outputs into it. Thank you in advance.